symbol not found in flat namespace '_PyExc_TypeError'
When I do this directly on my terminal, import works.
python3
sys.path.insert(1, "/Users/myuser/Documents/git/myproject/rtmidi-2.5.0/build/lib.macosx-13.0-arm64-cpython-311")
import rtmidi

When I try Live app and do the same in its Python environment, I get:
2024-11-03T19:55:42.053344: info: RemoteScriptMessage: (MyRemoteScript) dlopen(/Users/myuser/Documents/git/myproject/rtmidi-2.5.0/build/lib.macosx-13.0-arm64-cpython-311/rtmidi/_rtmidi.cpython-311-darwin.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace '_PyExc_TypeError'


This is same Mac OS system, same rtmidi folder to import, just different Python environments. I have compared them with sys.version and platform.platform() commands.
Directly on terminal:
3.11.10 (main, Sep  7 2024, 01:03:31) [Clang 15.0.0 (clang-1500.1.0.2.5)]
macOS-13.3.1-arm64-arm-64bit

On Live environment:
3.11.6 (main, Sep 26 2024, 16:43:33) [Clang 15.0.0 (clang-1500.1.0.2.5)]
macOS-13.3.1-arm64-arm-64bit

What else can be incompatible on Live environment and how to attempt to solve this issue? Can it be somehow too limited (if that's possible) so it can't load .so files and how to confirm this?
Thanks

I just found a workaround. I used compiled app so it doesn't depend on dependencies eg rtmidi in this case.
